# Eigen vectors and eigen values of sum of 2 related matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Consider *$A=U \Sigma U^{T}$* as the SVD of $A$ which is a positive definite symmetric matrix. What can we say about the eigen values and eigen vectors of $A+B, $  where, $B =(VU) \Sigma (VU)^{T}$ under the following cases?

1. $V$ is an orthonormal matrix.
2. $V$ is a diagonal orthonormal matrix

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @razivo ,  I tried writing the explicit form $(U+VU) \Sigma (U+VU)^{T} +B= U \Sigma U^{T} +VU \Sigma U^{T} + U \Sigma  (VU)^{T} + (VU) \Sigma (VU)^{T}. $

This is not an SVD by itself because of the cross terms.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is something useful that we can say about the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

In each case, note that $B = VAV^T$.

For case 1, there is nothing we can say outside of the usual statement regarding the eigenvalues of a sum of positive definite matrices. In particular, because $V$ is allowed to be any orthogonal matrix, it is possible to select $V$ such that $B$ becomes any orthogonal matrix whose eigenvalues are the same as $A$'s.

The most that we can say in this case (as in the general case of the sum of two symmetric matrices) is that [Weyl's inequality holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).

For case 2, note that $V$ must be diagonal with entries $\pm 1$. So, if $A$ is $n \times n$, we are limited to at most $2^{n-1}$ possibilities for $B$. Without more information about $A$, there is not much that we can say in general about what the eigenvalues of $A + B$.  However, the $A + B$ will necessarily be a multiple of a "pinching" of $2A$, which (as I elaborate on below in a specific case) gives us information about the eigenvectors.

---

For the specific case where $A$ has size $2m$ and $V = \operatorname{diag}(I,-I)$, we have
$$
VAV^T = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & -I} \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22}} \pmatrix{I & 0 \\ 0 & -I} = \pmatrix{A_{11} & -A_{12}\\ -A_{21} & A_{22}}
\\ \implies
A + B = 2\pmatrix{A_{11} & 0\\ 0 & A_{22}}.
$$
In other words, what we attain is a (multiple of a) "pinching" of $A$ (cf. Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*). There still isn't a lot that we can say about the eigenvalues. However, we know that we can necessarily find a basis of eigenvectors where $m$ will have $0$s in the first $m$ entries, and the other $m$ will have $0$s in the last $m$ entries.

Comment: How are we able to say the possibilities are limited to $n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $2^{n-1}$. This holds because there are $2^n$ possible matrices, but $V$ and $-V$ have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Ben. If I have a special case of V =diag(+1, -1 , +1, -1,...) , do you think we could deduce more about  the eigen values/vectors of A+B.

Comment: @wanderer In that particular case (and by extension, in the case where there are equally many $+1$'s and $-1$'s), I think there is something nice that can be said.

Comment: @wanderer See my latest edit. I suspect that a similar analysis can be applied to the general case where $V$ is diagonal with $\pm 1$'s.

Comment: I think in your specific example, $V^{T}$ is wrongly expanded as matrix form. It should be $diag(I, -I)$. The RHS is wrong as well.

Comment: @wanderer fixed

Comment: @wanderer aha, thanks for clarifying.