# What happens to eigenvalues and eigenvectors after a given matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Assume I have a square matrix $A$ with the following properties:

1. $A$ is positive definite
2. $A$ is symmetric
3. SVD of $A$ is $ A = U \Sigma U^{'} $

Now, I form a new matrix $B$ as follows:

> $b_{ij} = \alpha \times a_{ij} $ if $(i-j)$ is perfectly divisible by 2.

> $b_{ij} = 0 $ otherwise.
> (Note that $\alpha$ is a real scalar)

*My aim is to find the  eigen values and eigen vectors of $B$?
Are there any well known theorems that we could use to find the eigen values and eigen vectors of $B$? Can someone provide any guidance in  how to solve this problem.

Comment: As I say in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3763736/81360) to your other post, this will be a "pinching" of $A$. In other words, the resulting matrix is block-diagonal up to a permutation similarity. One block has size $\lceil n/2 \rceil$, the other has size $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think the matrix B has $2 \times 2$ diagonal blocks. I don't understand how you say there are 2 blocks of size $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ and $ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by "up to permutation similarity"?

Comment: Oh ok. I understand it now.I was wrong about how i understood block diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ denote the size of $A$. I'll focus on the case where $n$ is odd, but the case where the size is even is essentially the same. Let $P$ denote the permutation matrix whose columns are
$$
P = \pmatrix{e_1 & e_3 & \cdots & e_n & e_2 & e_4 & \cdots & e_{n-1}},
$$
where $e_j$ denotes the $j$th column of the size $n$ identity matrix. Verify that we have
$$
P^TBP = \alpha\pmatrix{A_{1} & 0 \\0 & A_2},
$$
where $A_1$ is the submatrix of $A$ attained by deleting the even rows and columns, and $A_2$ is the submatrix of $A$ attained by deleting the odd rows and columns. To find the eigenvalues of $B$, we can find the eigenvalues of $A_1$ and $A_2$ separately, then multiply these eigenvalues by $\alpha$.