# Scaling of a matrix and its impact on eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Given a positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ where $n$ is even, with known eigen values and eigen vectors, what can we say about the eigen values/vectors of a new matrix $B$ formed as

---

$b_{ij} = (1+\alpha) \times b_{ij}$ , when  $(i-j)$ mod 2 =0

$b_{ij} = (1-\alpha) \times b_{ij}$ , when  $(i-j)$ mod 2 =1

---

**In effect, we are scaling all the even diagonals of $A$ by $1+\alpha$ and all the odd diagonals by $1-\alpha$.**

NB: $\alpha$ is a real positive scalar.

Also , I understand that when $\alpha =1$ ,as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763764/what-happens-to-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-after-a-given-matrix-transformation/3764525#3764525), we could transform the matrix B to a block diagonal matrix and could find the eigen values  of $B$ easily. But my question is what happens when $\alpha$  is a generic scalar.

Also, If there does not exist any direct relation between eigen values of $A$ and $B$ ,is there any approximate function which I could use to approximate eigen values of $B$ using those of $A$?

Comment: `\pmod {...}` renders to $\pmod {...}$

Comment: I see no reason to expect the eigenvalues to be related in any understandable way. Do you have one? I suppose you could try computing the characteristic polynomial of $B$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$. You could probably get an explicit description of the linear term (i.e. the perturbation if $\alpha^2 = 0$).

Comment: You could try perturbation theory for small $\alpha$